API to know info about a contract address
Is there any API or database to get information about a contract about what dApp it belongs to or the type of dApp (DAO, Exchange, Game, Betting...).
I saw analyses of "X% of Ethereum contracts are DeFi" or "Only Y% are games", but I can't seem to find the raw data to make my own updated analysis of the ethereum chain current status.

I would try using DappRadar API. You can iterate through Dapps and look at contracts. They have automatically categorized all the contracts/dapp (you can look at tags) and they have 17k dapps and 50k NFT collections (as of July 2024) so you should be able to get some pretty detailed info! I hope this helps!
